# Can a rational function have an infinite number of dicontinuity points?

Tags: continuity, rational-functions

This is a question in our book, and the answer in the teacher's book is "No", and a friend of mine says that their teacher also says that a rational function always has a definite $n$ number of docontinuity points.

But I can think of a few functions that have an infinite number of discontinuity points;

1) $f(x)= \frac{1}{\sin x} $ which is discontinuous at every x value that satisfies $x= n\pi$ where $n$ is an integer. The same is also true for this function but with cosine and tan and their respective infinite sets of discontinuity points

2) $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} $ which is discontinuous over the whole interval $[-r,r]$ and has an infinte number of discontinuity points that belong to this interval

Now I think I'm wrong here because I'm not sure if these count as "rational functions" or not.

Comment: A rational function is the ratio of two polynomials. Neither your examples are.

Comment: to be a rational function, both the numerator and the denominator have to be polynomials so the book has it right.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, since a rational function is a quotient of two polynomial functions, since polynomial functions are continuous and since the quotient of two continuous functions is continuous, every rational function has *zero* points of discontinuity.

Comment: But what about a function like $\frac{x}{x-1}$ at $x=1$ ? That isnt continuous at that point, right?

Comment: SInce $1$ doesn't belong to the domain, it is meaningless to ask whether or not it is continuous there.

Comment: We could charity interpret OP's question as meaning poles rather than discontinuity points

Comment: @SamCassidy Let us see what the OP has to say about that.

Comment: @jośe Carlos Santos our book says that undefined points (ie points that dont belong to the domain) also count as discontinuity points. Alot of the examples on discontinuity points are also on rational functions. And I'm not sure what Sam Cassidy means by "poles" , but if he means vertical asymptotes (which I doubt he does) then it doesn't necessarily need to be one

Comment: @Dahen Really?! Then I guess that, for you, $\sqrt x$ is discontinuous at $-1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos pretty much. The book defines a dicontinuity point as any point that satisfies one or more of three conditions : 1) the function is undefined at that point 2) the limit of the function as x tends to that point doesn't exist 3)the limit of the function and the value of the function at that point aren't equal. I'm not sure about how accurate this is but it's what we've been going with for this past year